# Get VM GUI on a core server via VNC

Tags: virtualbox, display, gui, core

I have a linux server without GUI running several Windows 7 VMs. I would like to view the screen of the VMs. Is it possible to connect to the linux server with a desktop computer in order to display the VM's screen?

Thanks !

EDIT: I'm using VirtualBox 4 as a virtual software

Comment: Depends entirely what VM software you are running

Comment: I am using VirtualBox 4

Comment: Virtualbox has a built in VNC server. https://grenville.wordpress.com/2012/03/14/using-vnc-with-headless-virtualbox-vms/

Comment: Oh that's nice. Do you know if I need the Guest additions in order to make it work?

Comment: No, it is a host-side feature.

Answer (score 0):

As qasdfdsaq stated above, you can set up a RDP Server with VirtualBox.

But you need the VirtualBox Extension Pack installed first.